# Calling C dll from C#, return types slightly different

Tags: c#, c, dll, interop

I've written a dll in C which has functions I can call when referencing the DLL in C#. If I use a basic type like an int it works fine, but I have structs which are slightly different in C# than they are in C due to language differences. Here is an example. This is the function definition in C#:

```
[DllImport("hello_world_cuda.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern Batch Cut();
```

And here is it in C:

```
extern "C" Batch __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall Cut()
```

You can see the return type Batch is the same, but here is its definition in C#

```
class Envelope
{
    public byte[] Payload;
    public byte[] Signature;
}

class Batch
{
    public Envelope[] Messages;
    public int MsgCount;
}
```

And here is the definition in C

```
struct Envelope
{
public:
    char* Payload;
    char* Signature;
};

struct Batch
{
public:
    Envelope* Messages;
    int MsgCount;
};
```

How do I overcome these language differences in order to successfully make the DLL call in C#?

Comment: A character array in c is terminate with a '\0'.  So in c# if you are using a byte[] than make sure you add the '\0' as last byte[].

Comment: How does the DLL allocate memory? And who is responsible for deallocation. That's the first thing you need to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers in an unmanaged language do not map to managed arrays as you have done, this is why it is complaining.  `char` is (almost always, with very limited exceptions) an 8 bit value that maps well to `byte` in C# as you've noticed, but you need to make them pointers in the managed struct as well:

```cs
unsafe struct Envelope
{
    public byte* Payload;
    public byte* Signature;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is really close to working, but when I do this it only seems to retrieve the first char/byte instead of the whole array. Do I have to add a length tag to the property or something? (I also had to convert Messages in Batch to a pointer, the same issue is there, it only copies the first one)
EDIT: Never mind, it does copy the data, the debugger just only displays the first element. Thank you!

Comment: You've basically described how pointers work.  Ask yourself this:  Given the C++ class you have there, how would you know how long those entries are?  You can't, all you have is a memory address.  You can access it the same as you would access an array though.

Answer (score 2):

You should define `Envelope` and `Batch` as structs in C# too, and apply the [StructLaylout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netcore-3.1) attribute:

e.g.:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=0)]
struct Envelope
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did this but it still gave an error "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible", do you know how to resolve that? I searched the error and saw a suggestion to use an out variable instead of a return value, that gave a different error saying the array was not of the specified type. I tried changing the array types from byte to char but that didn't change anything.